# Can we use Abstract Class in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I attended one interview where below questions were asked by technical guy.

Does Abstract class have its own methods?

Does Parent Class means Abstract Class?

Where can we use Abstract class in Selenium WebDriver? (in real time project). Give one example/situation where you have used

Can any one please give me the answer for these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the inline answers.

Does Abstract class have its own methods?

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed. Source: [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Does Parent Class means Abstract Class?

> No, it need not be. Parent Classes can be Abstract Class or Concrete
>   Classes.

Where can we use Abstract class in Selenium WebDriver? (in real time project). Give one example/situation where you have used

> Example of Abstract vs Concrete Class: If you have complete requirements then you will go for a concrete class, but if you have a partial requirements in hand then you can go for Abstract Class.
>
> public abstract class AbstractWebDriverEventListener extends
>   java.lang.Object implements WebDriverEventListener
>
> Use this class as base class, if you want to implement a
>   WebDriverEventListener and are only interested in some events. All
>   methods provided by this class have an empty method body.

Comment: What is concrete class? @khaja

Comment: @ShaziyaLovingKhan, concrete class is a class which is not abstract and objects can be created of it.